# Include single quotation in url string in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

What is the correct way to pass the single quotes inside the [ ] in this url please in my Apps Script?

`https://{{domain}}/api/1.0.0/{apiKey}/appointments?where=['start,>=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00','end,<=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00']`

I have:

`var url = 'https://{{domain}}/api/1.0.0/' + {apiKey} + '/appointments?where=[' + ? + 'start,>=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00' + ? +',' + ? + 'end,<=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00' + ? + ']'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use double quote `"`.

```
var url = "https://{{domain}}/api/1.0.0/" + {apiKey} + "/appointments?where=['start,>=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00','end,<=,2017-05-26T07:23:46-07:00']";
```